# Oracle Text. Try to update column with context index

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I'm trying to update a column with a context index.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table(first_column NUMBER, text CLOB);
INSERT INTO new_table VALUES(1,'Oracle');
INSERT INTO new_table VALUES(2,'Text');
COMMIT;
CREATE INDEX idx_new_table_text ON new_table(text) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS ('SYNC ( ON COMMIT)');
```

With "PARAMETERS ('SYNC ( ON COMMIT)')" parameter I was able to add data to the table.
But I still can't update the data in this column or delete rows from this table.

```
UPDATE new_table SET text = 'new text' WHERE first_column = 3;
COMMIT;
```

Аnd after committing, I see errors:
"Commit failed" AND 
"ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
 ORA-06550: String 1, column 7:
 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of agruments in call to 'SYNCRN'"
Tell me, please, what should I do to make UPDATE and DELETE start working?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you running? Does it happen to be version 11.2.0.4? If so, this may be related to Bug 17501296 - Commit callback procedure ctxsys.syncrn is not in sync with 11.2.0.4 C-code

Comment: Your code works for me in version 12.2.

Comment: Yes, I use this particular version - "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production".

Comment: And if I can't use a higher version, can I somehow avoid this error?

Comment: I tried to call the following code:
begin
ctx_ddl.sync_index('idx_new_table_text');
end;
And got this error message:
"Error report -
ORA-06550: String 2, Column 1:
PLS-00904: insufficient privilege to access object CTXSYS.CTX_DDL
ORA-06550: String 2, Column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:"
And after referring to my DBA, I found out that this module is not installed. I think this is exactly the cause of the error. I'm right?